# Modal or auxiliary will

Tags: modal-verbs

Recently I saw the movie Kung Fu panda, and there was one interesting sentence.When Oogway is about to make the decision who the Dragon Warrior will be, Master Shifu says : ' He will now choose the Dragon Warrior". Why is the adverb now used with "will" here? Does the word "now" mean "soon" here? Or is the verb will used here as a modal verb?

Comment: One thing that's implied in your question, if I'm not mistaken, is that you think that being "a modal verb" and being "an auxiliary verb" are mutually exclusive, but actually it's not. A modal verb is also known as "modal auxiliary verb".

Comment: I would not say so, I meant that if it was not used here to construct future, then it could be used as a modal verb, referring to the present moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the adverb now used with "will" here?

To specify when in the future he will choose the Dragon Warrior, namely, immediately after that proclamation.

> Does the word "now" mean "soon" here?

Yes. We use "now" to refer to the present moment as well as just after the time of speaking. For example, "Get out of this room now!".

> Or is the verb will used here as a modal verb?

Originally (in ancient English) "will" was a modal verb. After all, stating something about the future tends to be stating a possibility, desire or belief rather than a (past) fact. Gradually this underlying modal meaning disappeared until today it is just a helper verb used to indicate future time and nothing more. Of course, there are remnants of the modal meaning, such as in the verb "will" meaning "desire". For example, "If you will, I can come."

Comment: Does it have here a modal meaning to your mind?

Comment: @Fatimahon: In this case no. This statement is made as a factual statement, one that he is certain will happen. There are other cases such as "Alright, I will go." which conveys a choice, which can be construed as modal. But here it does not seem to indicate that, because the event had clearly been planned in advance.

Comment: And what do you think about the meaning of voluntary intention, mentioned in the first answer?

Comment: @Fatimahon: Okay I just went to have a look at the full transcript; it says "**OOGWAY**: I sense the Dragon Warrior is among us. **SHIFU**: Citizens of the Valley of Peace! Master Oogway will now choose... the Dragon Warrior!". It seems that this specific part of the event was not planned but was due to Oogway suddenly announcing that he sensed the dragon warrior. Some people do say that "will" is still used as a modal verb but others think it's more or less vanished.

Comment: @Fatimahon: In this case, it could be intended to mean "Master Oogway has decided to choose ..." but that is adequately conveyed by the pure future tense so many native speakers would not identify it as modal. I personally think Shifu is saying nothing more than "Master Oogway is about to choose ...".

Comment: As for me I also think that the meaning of this sentence is just the same as in the sentence ... Is about to choose, but we were taught that this usage does not belong to the sphere of a Future Simple, that is why I thought it might contain the modal meaning, Is it Grammatical to use Future Simple for planned actions for native speakers of English?

Comment: @Fatimahon: Yes it is grammatical. Some people hence say that it is a modal verb that is used for future planned events, and historically it was so, but others say that modern native speakers of English no longer understand it as a modal in most cases. I am one of the latter, and I think that by default "will" with an infinitive simply denotes future time, unless the context requires a modal interpretation. Most native speakers go by instinct anyway and will not (modal!) be able to explain clearly what they interpret it as. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Will_and_would)

Comment: @Fatimahon Aside from the question of whether futurity is a mode or a tense, the term ***modal verb*** in English grammar designates a class of verbs with distinct morphological and syntactical properties, not distinct semantic properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad topic but I am going to try to keep it brief.

Use v. Usage in English

*Use* refers to the structure in the language and *Usage* usually means the way the language is employed in everyday life. So, while "will" is taught as the future tense, the usage of "will" is more common to make a prediction, a promise, or in this case, a declaration of intention. In BrE *shall* is used to indicate the difference between the two, but it has fallen out of favor in the US.

Anyway, it's only a cartoon, not literature.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and what do you think is the meaning of the word "now" in this sentence?

Comment: @Fatimahon: I disagree with Gandalf about the splitting of the verb. It is definitely correct English grammar to have an adverb between the helper verb and the main verb (infinitive). For example: "He will quickly realize his error."